# How to get list of all users who have sudo privileges in mac?

Tags: mac, sudo

I can parse the contents of the sudoers file and get the information. But I am looking for a simpler solution like using some command.

Answer (score 2):

By default, OS X, now macOS includes Administrators (admins) as part of the sudoers file, so you don't really need to parse it unless someone has been manually adding to the sudoers file.  If you fall in the former group, you can simply create the following alias:

```
alias who-sudo = 'dscl . -read /groups/admin | grep GroupMembership'
```

The `dscl` command is your friend...